# PHP opens file with too strict of permissions

Tags: php, permissions

When I open a file using `fopen($filename, 'w+')` (that is, reading and writing), it creates the file with permissions like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 2010-12-09 12:02 TransactionImport-7.txt
```

Then, when other processes try to open the file, they can't do it. How can I get the file to open with less strict permissions?

I can't change the permissions after I close the file because other programs need to read the file while it's still being written. When I try to change them before with `chmod()`, it makes it so my script can't write to the file at all.

Comment: Are you closing the resource with fclose($file_handle) when you're done?

Comment: Yes. And because I can't just type "yes" because of Stack Overflow's retarded character minimum, I'm typing more stuff here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `touch` before `fopen` with `w+`

such as

```
touch($filename);
chmod($filename, YOUR_PREFER_PERMISSION);
fopen($filename, 'w+');
```

**OR**

`umask` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Comment: I tried this exact thing before and it messed things up in new and confusing ways. However, the reason turned out to be indirectly related. This is ultimately what got it working.

Comment: will be great if you post up what exactly solve the problem..?

Comment: I had another script that happened to be running over and over at the same time and it kept overwriting my file.

Comment: ic, will you consider to use `tmpfile` like http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php ?